# How do communication networks physically direct traffic?

Tags: routing, switch, cable, isp

I’m curious as to how this would work. I have an ISP that uses Coaxial Cable to deliver its services (this company was one of the original cable TV providers in the neighbourhood, hence why coax and not fibre is used).

In the neighbourhood, the coax cable is directly (I assume directly) connected from my router to a hub on the street. These are typical street communication hubs, the ones you see on people’s lawns. There are multiple hubs on each street, each with 5-10 coax cables (I can assume from other houses) plugged into it. These cables are combined into a main cable, which I assume goes to the headend, then my traffic gets routed. I understand the software side of internet routing, and how electrical pulses represent a digital signal (even though coaxial is analog).

It’s clear how, or at least that, the “signals” from these coaxial cables are combined and sent over this main cable. Otherwise, there would be thousands of individual cables going to the carrier.

Combining makes sense. My question is: in the opposite direction, when they’re split, how is my “traffic” (whether it be internet, TV, or even landline telephone) directed towards my house, and my house alone?

I am not sure if those hubs are just big splitters (and thus in reverse, combiners). They don’t appear to be connected to power and thus I don’t think they act as a switch. As a sub-question: in a traditional coaxial splitter (the ones you buy at the store, 1 to 2), would output two receive the signals intended for output one (even if in addition to the ones intended for output two)?

Whether it be over coax, or fibre, or even old fashion telephone cables, how does the ISPs downstream “traffic” intended for me not end up coming out of my neighbours cable, or even at another house blocks away?

I assume the type of cable doesn’t make a difference, I’m just curious how the signals, whether in the neighbourhood or across the entire ISP, are physically directed.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and networks not under your direct control are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: "Cable" is used in business as well. Every office I've had for over a decade had a cable connection as a backup.

Comment: @RonMaupin It seems to me you are misunderstanding the question.  This isn't about home networking. It's (mostly) about the professionally managed network of a business: the cable company.  But it also asks about fibre and DSL, so it's not well-posed, as each has a different answer.

Comment: @user1521620, remember that questions about networks you do not directly control are also off-topic here.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I didn't click for more details.  Would be on-topic / a fair question at  Information Security Stack Exchange
https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is my “traffic” ... directed towards my house, and my house alone?

It isn't. Cable is a one-to-many broadcast medium. Everyone on the node sees the same downstream signal. In a modern network, that signal is encrypted so only the intended modem will understand it, but every modem hears it. In the upstream, there's a fair bit of port-to-port isolation on the distribution taps (what you're calling a "hub"), so what you transmit isn't so readily heard by other modems. (Not that they're listening on those channels. Plus the upstream is encrypted, too.)

Comment: I feel like this post should expand a bit on other link types, as OP's assumption that "type of cable doesn't make a difference" is not entirely right – cable in the "cable TV" sense is one-to-many, but cable in the more general sense (telephone wires, etc) definitely isn't, but the answer implies that they all work the same way. (Similarly fiber being used in both ways, one-to-one Ethernet and one-to-many GPON...)

Comment: Thanks for answering. What's the encryption standard used?

Comment: @user1686 I always wondered how telephone cables work, since they aren't "one-to-many" andtraditional landlines don't have "routers", how is it that, for example, my neighbours home phone doesn't ring when someone calls my number?

Comment: If you go back far enough, landlines (POTS) were one-to-many - ever heard of a "party line". They died out in the 70's. Yes, the PSTN does have "routers". We call them phone switches. There are many, MANY places on the internet describing all of this.

Comment: @StackQsUp: No, they _do_ have "routers", they're just called "[telephone exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange)" or "switching systems". (Starting with [electromechanical ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strowger_switch) built in 1890s, _long_ before IP and packet networks were a thing, now they're fully [electronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMS-100) of course.) There's plenty of historical sites/[texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phreaking)/YT [videos](https://www.youtube.com/@ConnectionsMuseum) about how telephone systems worked.

Comment: [Here's a museum tour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_m4K5Q5yRU) of a telephone museum with manual exchanges and *several types* of electro-mechanical ones. As user1686 said, the modern ones are just electronic boxes with wires plugged in and they don't belong in museums yet, but the ancient electro-mechanical ones are *truly something to behold*. Also pretty expensive, so they used party lines to save money by using less phone lines. And yes, they actually use the equipment in the tour and you can see it work. (@StackQsUp)

Comment: by jumping down the rabbit hole for 4 hours, I stumbled across something related to that: [here](http://www.evan-doorbell.com/production/HowBPhreak05.mp3) at 24:23 is an actual sound recording of an electro-mechanical exchange as background noise on a phone call to the exchange. btw this [whole series](http://www.evan-doorbell.com/production/group1.htm) should be fascinating to any computer geek

Comment: @StackQsUp another thing you may want to read about is the difference between circuit switching and packet switching

Comment: Late reply but thanks for sharing this. This is fascinating stuff. Thank you.